# Mysql Select Query with match and against issue

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code to perform a search

```
 SELECT d.deal_id,
    d.deal_title,
    d.friendly_url
    FROM wp_deals AS d
   WHERE MATCH (d.deal_title) AGAINST ('Historic China eight day tour' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
   GROUP BY d.deal_id
```

It works fine.and give 14 results.
one of them is

Great Sandy Straits two night Natural Encounters Tour for two with sunset cruise & more. Up to $1,071 off!

But when I search for "with" or "more" it becomes

```
SELECT d.deal_id,
   d.deal_title,
   d.friendly_url
 FROM wp_deals AS d
WHERE MATCH (d.deal_title) AGAINST ('more' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
GROUP BY d.deal_id


 SELECT d.deal_id,
   d.deal_title,
   d.friendly_url
   FROM wp_deals AS d
   WHERE MATCH (d.deal_title) AGAINST ('with' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
   GROUP BY d.deal_id
```

and does not give any result although with and more both are their. I am not an expert with this type of search query.

But

When i search with "tour" that is also their it works fine.whats going on their.
could not understand as "tour","with" and "more" all contains four letters and also their in title.

You People are Genius..

What you suggest so it will workout.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Boolean full-text searches the stopword list applies and common words such as “some” or “then”...  are stopwords and do not match if present in the search string : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//fulltext-boolean.html

Stopword list : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html

The best known solutions are disable the list or add / remove values ​​from it : [How to reset stop words in MYSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796688/how-to-reset-stop-words-in-mysql)

Also  :

```
SELECT d.deal_id,
   d.deal_title,
   d.friendly_url
FROM 
   wp_deals AS d
WHERE MATCH (d.deal_title) AGAINST ('+more*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
GROUP BY d.deal_id
```