# How to identify stopwords before making mysql query

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, full-text-search

I'm trying to set up a text search for a webapp.  My mysql query is the following:

`SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE MATCH (c1,c2,c3) AGAINST (:keyStr IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

I want all words in :keyStr to be matched, so keyStr looks like:

`:keyStr='+word[0]* +word[1]* +word[2]* + ... +word[n]*'`

If any word[x] is a stopword or less than the min word length the query returns a null.  I think the best solution is to remove the '+' from a stopword or remove the stopword entirely from :keyStr.

Is there any good ways to do this?  Do I need to check if any word[x] is in stopwords_list before the query is made?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796688/how-to-reset-stop-words-in-mysql

Comment: but i don't want to disable stop words

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to accomplish this with javascript is:

```
var apart = "Some +example search that I made up".toLowerCase().replace(/[\+\-\?]*/g, '').split(' '),
    stop_words = ['the', 'that', 'a', 'example'],
    min_word_length = 1;

// filter the array to remove stop words
apart.filter( function( item ) {
    if ( item.length < min_word_length ) return false;
    return stop_words.indexOf( item ) === -1;
});
```

Edit: though in a pseudo-code sense, the above code would work, here is a PHP solution

```
$query = "This is my example search query";

$search = explode(' ', $query);

$stop_words = array('is', 'a', 'the');

$terms = array_filter($search, function($item){
    return !in_array($item, $stop_words);
});

$formatted = array_map(function($term){
    return '+'.mysql_escape_string($term).'*';
}, $terms);

// :keyStr = implode(' ', $formatted);
```

Comment: This would work.  But, mysql is already checking every word against that stopword list and for min_word_length.  
Checking for stopwords on the client side seems like I'm doing the job twice.